# Is this case distinction correct

Tags: absolute-value

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x|x-1|=\begin{cases} -x(x-1) &x\leq1 \\
x(x-1) & x>1 \end{cases}$.

Is this case distinction correct? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. The comment has a 15 character limit, so I had to say more XD

Comment: This looks OK. You could also write it as $$x|x-1|=\begin{cases} -x(x-1) &x < 1 \\
x(x-1) & x \geq 1 \end{cases}$$ or as $$x|x-1|=\begin{cases} -x(x-1) &x \leq 1 \\
x(x-1) & x \geq 1 \end{cases}$$ since when $x=1$ both (sub)formulas evaluate to $0$ (i.e. both formulas agree when $x=1).$